# How to fool Jenkins into thinking all branches already ran in multibranch pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm using multibranch pipelines to build a project in a git repo with many (mostly dormant) branches. The various Jenkinsfiles are all stored in the git repo.

The multibranch pipeline jobs are all defined using the job-dsl plugin. I have a problem when I run the job-dsl scripts; even when a job-dsl job definition wasn't updated (and the multibranch pipeline job wasn't updated), Jenkins queues all branches for build. Due to the large number of branches (and possibly some jobs/branches that run on the master itself), this eventually causes the master to crash.

How can I mark all branches as "already built" and avoid this massive redundant build event when I run my job-dsl generation job?

`Jenkins 2.89.4
job-dsl 1.68`

Answer (score 2):

Specifying an `id` for the SCM source solved that problem a while ago for me:

```
multibranchPipelineJob {
  branchSources {
    github {
      id('some-id')
      // ..
    }
  }
}
```